# Python LoRa MQTT with Paho Mqtt NameError: name 'payload' is not defined

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, lora, lorawan

I created a packet-forwarding script on my Raspberry Pi LoRa gateway to forward packets to a broker through MQTT using the Paho mqtt Python library. I managed to do the packet forwarding using my own payload values.

But now am failing to have a global payload variable from the `on_rx_done/on_publish` functions that have the self constructor that picks the payload values from LoRa. I would like to define the variable payload and give it `self.read_payload` in the publish function. But my approach is failing. In my current execution I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/PythonxxxxxxPost.py", line 26, in <module>
    ret = client1.publish("xxxxxxxxxxx",payload) #topic
NameError: name 'payload' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho             #mqtt library
import os
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from xxxxx.LoRa import *
from xxxxx.board_config import BOARD

ACCESS_TOKEN='xxxxxx' #Token of your device
broker="xxx.xxx.xxx" #host name
port=xxxx

BOARD.setup()

class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):
    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

    def start(self):
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
        while True:
            sleep(.5)
            rssi_value = self.get_rssi_value()
            status = self.get_modem_status()
            sys.stdout.flush()

    def on_publish(self,client,userdata):
        global payload
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)
       #print(bytes(payload).decode("utf-8",'ignore'))
        print("data published to xxxxx \n")
        pass
    global client1
    client1= paho.Client("control1") #create client object
    client1.on_publish = on_publish #assign function to callback
    client1.username_pw_set(ACCESS_TOKEN) #access token 
    client1.connect(broker,port,keepalive=60)
   
    def send(self,client,userdata):      
        global payload
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)
        #payload = '{"id":"123456789","lat":48.596,"lon":-1.532}'
    ret = client1.publish("xxxxxxxxxxxx",payload) #topic
    print("Please check LATEST TELEMETRY field of your device")
    print(payload);
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You haven't declared your global variable payload at the beginning of the program. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function

Comment: Is there a way i can assign it self.read_payload(nocheck=True) at the beginning of the program?

Answer (score 0):

```py
    def on_publish(self,client,userdata):
        global payload
```

Where does `payload` come from? Asserting `global payload` means that you have it defined at the global level, hence the name. But it is not defined. So of course you get an error...